# Sort nodes in XML using DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, domparser

How can I sort the XML nodes according to the  tag and append in 
 the new XML using DOM parser or can it be done using DOM parser. We've 
 used DOM parser extensively for appending nodes into a new file but I am   not able to sort the nodes.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Input.xml

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <Configs>
        <Value>defaultValue</Value>
        <Config name="test1">
            <title>Title 1</title>
            <author>Author1</author>
            <value>5600</value>
            <order>02</order>
        </Config>
        <Config name="test2">
            <title>Title 2</title>
            <author>Author2</author>
            <Value>6100</Value>
            <order>01</order>
        </Config>
    </Configs>
    <Ratings>
        <body>
            <Items name="ac_object1">
                <something1>something1</something1>
                <value>someValue1</value>
                <order>02</order>
            </Items>
            <Items name="op_object2">
                <something1>something2</something1>
                <value>someValue2</value>
                <order>03</order>
            </Items>
            <Items name="vt_object3">
                <something1>something3</something1>
                <value>someValue3</value>
                <order>01</order>
            </Items>
        </body>
    </Ratings>
</rss>
```

Expected Output.xml

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <Configs>
        <Value>defaultValue</Value>
        <Config name="test2">
            <title>Title 2</title>
            <author>Author2</author>
            <Value>6100</Value>
            <order>01</order>
        </Config>
        <Config name="test1">
            <title>Title 1</title>
            <author>Author1</author>
            <value>5600</value>
            <order>02</order>
        </Config>
    </Configs>
    <Ratings>
        <body>
            <Items name="vt_object3">
                <something1>something3</something1>
                <value>someValue3</value>
                <order>01</order>
            </Items>
            <Items name="ac_object1">
                <something1>something1</something1>
                <value>someValue1</value>
                <order>02</order>
            </Items>
            <Items name="op_object2">
                <something1>something2</something1>
                <value>someValue2</value>
                <order>03</order>
            </Items>
        </body>
    </Ratings>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do this using low-level DOM interfaces. Here's how to do it in XSLT 3.0 (which you can call from Java after installing Saxon-HE):

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform> version="3.0">
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[*/order]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="number(order)"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

With a few extra lines of code you could also do it using XSLT 1.0, which comes bundled with the JDK.

How it works:

- The `xsl:mode` declaration says that the default action for elements is to copy the element and then process its children
- `xsl:strip-space` says ignore whitespace in the input
- `xsl:output` says add indentation in the output
- The `xsl:template` rule says that when processing an element that has `order` elements among its grandchildren, copy the start and end tag, and process the children in sorted order of the numeric value of their `order` child element.

Comment: Thank you but I have to filter through lots of elements. The input xml file is pretty large. Plus according to the input parameters, we have to make changes to the base xml and create a new XML file. Hence, i thought it would be easier to dig into the elements and do the operations such as copying nodes and updating values. Sorting is the only thing that stumped me using DOM parser.

Comment: Everything you say seems to strengthen the case for using a high-level language like XSLT for the job rather than using low-level DOM calls. It's your call, of course.